# Variable Substitution in SQLite using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, substitution

I am trying to figure out how to combine two SQLite queries. Both of them work fine independently but when I put them together with `AND` they do not work. I think the problem is that I do not know how to pass the variables properly.
First query that works:

```
var1 = 10
mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'AB', 'AC']
c.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column1=(?) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", (mylist[2],))
```

This line also works:

```
params = [5,0,1]
query = ("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column2 NOT IN (%s)" % ','.join('?' * len(params)))
c.execute(query, params)
```

I have been trying to combine these two statements without success:

```
query = ("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column2 NOT IN (%s) AND column1=(?)" % ','.join('?' * len(params)))
c.execute(query, params, mylist[2])
```

In case anyone finds this helpful, my final solution looked like this:

```
query = ("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column1 = (?) AND column2 NOT IN (%s) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1" % ','.join('?' * len(params)))
    c.execute(query, [mylist[2]] + params)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `execute()` must be a sequence containing all the SQL parameters.

So you have to construct a single list with the values from both original lists:

```
c.execute(query, params + [list[2]])
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. I deleted my earlier comment because the fault was how I was formatting my query. I'll adjust my question above so it is formatted correctly.